# Automate fast download

Tags: performance, ubuntu-18.04, aria2

When you click on a file to download, can you make it so Aria2 (or Axel) automatically accelerates the download process, without going to the terminal to download?  Also, the file I am attempting to download is 3.7GB large, if it matters.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by accelerating the download? Downloads move at the speed determined by the source, network, and client. Accelerators typically employed certain nonstandard "cheats" that have a risk of failing or corrupting the download with the chance of making it run a little faster.

Comment: So I would have to have a much faster network connection to have faster downloads?

Comment: Your internet connection is only one part of the system that impacts your download speed.

Comment: It may be possible with a browser plugin. Since aria2 can split the file into several chunks and download them independently, if the server allows it, the file will likely download more quickly compared to the time when only one connection to the server is used.